# Adding a page indicating that a website is in maintenance

Tags: httpd

I use **Spring MVC** + **Apache tomcat** + **Apache httpd** and I am seeking for best practices in order to redirect all http requests to a page indicating to my users that the website is in maintenance. FYI, my website will be hosted on **Cloudfoundry**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good solution is to use a simple `.htaccess` to redirect the requests.

Comment: Thanks Aurelio. Do I have to restart httpd in order for changes to it to be picked up?

Comment: @balteo Usually this depends on your Apache configuration. If you aren't sure of your config, just restart ;)